# How to make right configuration to create SPARQL endpoint

Tags: apache, cpanel, sparql, httpd.conf, fuseki

I have a website domain from cpanel , and I want to make redirect from external URL to internal server (FUSEKI server) in order to create public SPARQL endpoint so I use Apache server to redirect from public site (e.g `http://site/sparql`) to the backend server (`http://localhost:3030/ds/query`) 
so I put this codes to httpd.conf

```
RewriteRule ^/sparql$ /usr/lib/fuseki/pages/sparql.html [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} query=
RewriteRule . http://localhost:3030/dataset/query [P]
```

in directory  section on httpd.conf, but unfortunately no result.

1. in which part of httpd.conf must I put this code?
2. how to connect between httpd.conf and my real website in cpanel?
3. should make Fuseki server turn on forever through cmd?

Comment: Most Stack Overflow users will appreciate it if you write carefully and using standard grammar and punctuation.  Minor mistakes aren't a big problem, but there's no need for more than one question mark.  It's also appreciated to keep the question to the technical details.    Apache doesn't get configured any differently whether you're a "beginner in all server domain and want some help" or not.  The *content* of the question isn't bad, but you'll get better answers if you write in the same way that you hope your answers will be written.

Comment: Duplicated at answers.semanticweb.com http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/28961/how-to-make-right-configuration-to-create-sparql-endpoint .

Answer (score 1):

use httpd as a "reverse proxy"

```
ProxyPass /YourDatabase/query  http://localhost:3030/YourDatabase/query   max=3
```

If you have `<VirtualHost>` then it goes inside that block.